# Prevent page from reloading after onchange a select menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I apologize if this is a very simple question, however I am not able to find any answers or don't know what I am doing wrong here.Also I am new to `ajax` and `jquery`. Thanks for helping in advance!

I have a select menu which I want to submit to the page on change I have the following:

```
<from action="" method="post">
<select name="option">
<option value="a">a </option>
<option value"b">b </option>
<option value"c">c</option>
</select></form>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$('#option').change, (function(e)  
{ 
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "",
        data: $("form.option").serialize(),
        success: function() {     
        }
    });
    return false;
});
</script>
```

and to check if it has submitted

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['option'])) {
    echo '<br />The ' . $_POST['option'] . ' submit button was pressed<br />';
}
?>
```

The form is submitted fine, however the page is still reloading on change, is there a way to stop the reloading of the page?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `onsubmit` `return false`.

Comment: `option` is the `name` of the element not `id` and moreover you are serializing the `element` with `class` name within `form` as `$("form.option")` which doesn't exist..

Comment: @Pyromonk where would that go? sorry for not knowing

Comment: there is no submit in the code you've posted. Unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: @hakre.. Oh, But that doesn't respond to **[jquery selectors](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/fffhmfq8/)** as per your statement.. Correct me if am wrong..

Comment: And also with  `url: "",` where you are posting the `form` to?

Comment: I want to post the value back to the current page

Comment: **`<from action="" method="post">`** FROM?? Surely it should be `<form....>`

Comment: @Ria, [`<form onsubmit="javascript: return false;"></form>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037069/what-is-the-meaning-of-onsubmit-return-false-javascript-jquery).

Comment: @RiggsFolly I want to resubmit the value to the current page I am on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<select id="option" name="option">
<option value="a">a </option>
<option value"b">b </option>
<option value"c">c</option>
</select>
```

And your jquery should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  $('#option').change(function()  
  { 
      var option_val = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "",
        data: "option="+option_val,
        success: function(res) 
        {  
            alert(res)   
        }
      });
  });
</script>
```

Simple Example :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['option'])) {
    echo '<br />The ' . $_POST['option'] . ' submit button was pressed<br />';
    die;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>temporary test</title>
</head>
<body>
<select id="option">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#option').change(function(){
        var option_val = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "",
        data: "option="+option_val,
        success: function(res) 
        {  
            alert(res)   
        }
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking, however when checking for the value that is submitted noting is echoed back out in the php function

Comment: May be you have to set the `url: "",` to `url: "url_where_u_want_to_send",` .
If you leave `url: "",` the ajax call will request to current page url.

Comment: I do want it to submit the value to the current url, but I wasn't sure if this is the correct way when using java. Is it?

Comment: Can you tell me where did you write this code? 
`<?php
if (isset($_POST['option'])) {
    echo '<br />The ' . $_POST['option'] . ' submit button was pressed<br />';
}
?>` I mean, in the same page ?

Comment: Yes it was written in the same page

Comment: I am so sorry however, noting seems to be happening, would have expected the page to just stop after echoing out the $_POST['option'], as it was placed in before the </head>. It seems like the value is not submitted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146656/discussion-between-m-deepak-and-ria).

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['option'])) {
    echo '<br />The ' . $_POST['option'] . ' submit button was pressed<br />';
    exit;
}

?>    
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="option" id="option">
        <option value="a">a</option>
        <option value="b">b</option>
        <option value="c">c</option>
    </select>
</form>
<div id="msg">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../library/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$('#option').change(function(e)  
{ 
    e.preventDefault();  
    var data=""; 
    data=$("#option").val();

   $.ajax({

        type: 'post',
        url: "",
        data: {option:data},
        success: function(result) {
            $('#msg').html(result);
        }
    });
    return false;

});

</script>
```

your output will be in `div` tag which `option` is submit the `form`

you can also display in `alert`

```
alert(result);
```

or using console in developer tool

```
console.log(result);
```