# How to submit form multiple times when using contenteditable on pressing enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code, it works fine and gives an alert message as many times as I want, but submits the form only once.

```
$("div[contenteditable]").keypress(function (evt) {
  var keycode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
  if (keycode  == 13) { //Enter key's keycode
  // $("#subcmt_smt").submit();
  alert('cool');
  return false;
  }  
});
```

How do I get it to submit the form every time?

Comment: did you try removing return false ?

Comment: You can [refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037069/what-is-the-meaning-of-onsubmit-return-false-javascript-jquery)

Comment: but i want to submit form on enter and if i will remove return false then enter will not submit the form

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(".content").keypress(function(evt) {
    var keycode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
    if (keycode == 13) { //Enter key's keycode
        $(".myForm").submit();
        alert('Form submitted, then this alert came. Try again.');
        return false;
    }
});

$(".myForm").submit(function(event) {
    alert("Handler for .submit() called.");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
 <form action="/" class="myForm">
  <textarea></textarea>
 </form>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't want to use input tag

Comment: You are using what?

Comment: actually i am making a comment system using <div contenteditable="true" >as my textarea and i am using the above code to submit the form on enter without going to the next line i works fine but only for once

Comment: Can you please add some information to your answer, many people are not looking down in the comments. Thank you.